# Terminology re Bijection elements vs. Relation elements

Tags: functions, terminology

Suppose I have bijection $X \rightarrow Y$. 
Is there a specific term for an element of $X$, which conveys the fact that 
the element can only map to one element of $Y$? 
E.g. "key" ?

Now suppose I have an $N:M$ relation $R \rightarrow S$.
Is there a specific term for an element of $R$, which conveys the fact that
the element can map to M elements of $S$? 
I.e. a term distinct from the above term for a bijection?

I am hoping, if possible, for terms which are nouns, not adjective, and terms
which are not negative, e.g. "non-key"
However all answers are welcome.

Comment: I don't understand this question.  In a bijection all elements of X have the same property they are all equally bijective.  There is no key element more important to its bijectivity en any other.  Can you give an example of such an element so we can get a better understanding of the concept you are trying to express.

Comment: Understood, no element is more important. The terms I am hoping for would apply to any element of the bijection, or relation, respectively. I only used the word "key" because saying <blank> seemed a worse way to say "I honestly don't know what the terms might be."

Comment: Do you mean 'key' as in key value pair/database lookup?

Comment: Yes, but only in the sense that "key" was only hackneyed analogy my background could suggest. A straw to grasp at, 99% sure it wasn't the term.

Answer (score 0):

The name for the set X in a function $ f : X \to Y $ is the domain of the function f.

The term for x in the formula $f(x)$ is the argument.  Argument is also used when talking about relations.

Comment: Bummer. Perhaps I lack the background to state the question clearly. Let me try an example: Imagine I have an ID badge which includes my thumbprint, plus the statement my eyes are brown. Are there no math terms for thumbprint/brown respectively, which distinguish the fact that while many people have brown eyes, only 1 person has my thumbprint?

Comment: I'm willing to take "no", but I'm also wondering if my question is both trivial and vanishingly arcane. I.e. no one has ever found any utility to justify coining distinguishing terms.

Comment: In database theory such a quality would be called a "candidate key".  If you said 'Uniquely identifying property' I suspect most people would understand you however its not really something that gets explored in mathematics that much.  At least the mathematics I've been exposed to.